# Convert meta tags in txt file to .po / .mo file

Tags: wordpress, converters, meta-tags

I hope somebody can save a noob: We have a [simple multi language site](http://www.easypsim.com) and want to move it to wordpress. Problem: We had it translated like this: [Example Translation](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ijy0c9bt9iksco7/de.inc.txt) and it looks like the [theme I want](http://dante.swiftideas.net/) in wordpress handles multilanguage in .po and .mo files.

All the texts remain the same and we clearly can't translate the whole site again. Is there an easy way to convert the text files? What would the most hassle-free method be?
Any help, tips, or recommendation is hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the .po files have a complete different structure then the file shown

```
###############
# meta
###############
define("L_TITLE_HOME", "HOME");
define("L_TITLE_REFERENCE", "Referenzen");
define("L_TITLE_SOFTWARE", "Unsere Software");
define("L_TITLE_COMPANY", "Über uns");
define("L_TITLE_PARTNER", "Für Partner");
define("L_TITLE_INVESTOR", "Für Investoren");
```

the gettext system doesn't recognize this type of files, so the best way i see you gonna have to copy the original .po file on your theme, rename it and then make the input off the translated vars manually.

But the best way in the the other languages its to have them translated directly on the respective .po files to avoid conflicts like this.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! The structure of the file looks pretty simple though - would it be possible to convert the original to a spreadsheet and convert that to a .po?

Comment: well the problem its the .po files are not just simple texts.. like this example
[code]

#. Text in function
#: realhomes/comments.php:11
msgid "(%) Comments"
msgstr "(%) Comentários"

[/code]

the translated strings inside the .po file are related to the position inside the respective files on you project so i think would be better and more accurate for you to just copy and paste the strings on a new .po file

Comment: like if you actual .po file its named like en_US and want to translate to spanish for example just copy and paste the file and change the name to es_ES and open with POEdit and copy and paste the respective translations inside the field relative.

Unfortunately you can't just convert a file to a .po file directly